# Xcode 6.3.1 App installation failed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Can't install app on real device after upgrading Xcode to 6.3.1.
Device and Xcode restarting doesn't help.
Any workarounds?

[image: error message]

Comment: Try removing your provisioning profile and letting Xcode request a new one. Or set the provisioning profile in build settings to automatic.

Comment: Read the device log at Xcode > Window > Devices and Xcode log at Console.app, might be something useful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally problem solved by executing `pod update`.